# System.out.printIn() not working on my code

Tags: java

it is showing me "cannot find symbol method printIn(java.lang.string)
please what is the error, i have used 3 different IDES. 
whats wrong with the System.out.printIn()

```
    public class Account
    {
    private String owner;
    private int balance;

    public Account (String name)
    {
        owner = name;
        balance = 0;
    }  
    public void deposit(int anAmount)
    {
        balance += anAmount;
    }
    public int withdraw(int anAmount)
    {
        int amountWithdrawn;
        if (anAmount <= balance )
            amountWithdrawn = anAmount;
        else
            amountWithdrawn = balance;

        balance -= amountWithdrawn;

        return amountWithdrawn;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.printIn("Owner =" + owner +"    Balance=" +   balance);
    }


}
```

Comment: it's println with a L lowercase, not printIn with i uppercase...

Comment: The `ln` in `println` stands for *line* by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not `printIn()`. You typed letter `I` for Ikea

That is `println()`  you had to use letter `l` for lima